# how to update multiple json encode data in single column field?

Tags: laravel-5.8

array:2 [▼
  0 => "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIACAYAAAD0eNT6AABNq0lEQVR42u3dCZwcVZ3A8Uq6uqu6uqYnx2RykBBCEmIgQCAJSTiUQ1cQEBDUFVRcQVhALg9UUIH1xAVcXHQBBUUEFhREBXHF9eKW3RUQBQVclMso ▶"
  1 => "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQAAAAEACAYAAABccqhmAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAAlwSFlzAACxKgAAsSoBYacs7wAAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAd3d3Lmlua3NjYXBlLm9yZ5vuPBoAACAASURBVHic7Z13 ▶"
]

code:
  $multi_image = $request->file('multi_image');

```
    if ($multi_image == '') 
    {

            $data[] = 'null';
    }

    else 
    {
            $file = $request->file('multi_image');

                for($i = 0 ; $i< count($file); $i++)
                {
                    $data[]= base64_encode(file_get_contents($file[$i]));

                }
    }



    $sort = $request->input('category_id');
    $order = Category::where('id','=',$sort)->first();



    $item = new Item();
    $item->admin_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $item->category_id = $request->input('category_id');
    $item->category_sort_order = $order->sort_order;
    $item->name = $request->input('name');
    $item->description = $request->input('description');
    $item->image = $image;
    $item->multi_image = json_encode($data);
    // $item->currency = '₹';
    $item->price = $request->input('price');
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more about what you are trying to execute?

Comment: i want to store multiple-image with convert base64 encode and stored in single column field in mysql.

Comment: Thank u for your response @HimanshuBansal

Comment: And what kind of problem you are facing? Please update your question with lil' more details

Comment: i want edit & delete single image or element

Comment: eg: i have a two array. i want edit to array of object 1. how to this?

Comment: can you provide your mysql structure and how are you trying to insert the images in mysql. Preferably if you can provide with your code. And why are you storing images on DB? Normally only the name is stored in database. And please update on question... will be helpful for everyone else too

Comment: how to update my code in stack overflow?

Comment: click edit on your question and paste your code then select your code and click codeblock '{}' icon.. it will highlight your code automatically

Comment: just retrieve your $item like `$item = App\Item::where('admin_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();` update item `$item->multi_image = json_encode($data); `save it `$item->save();`

Comment: this code like insert multi_image

Comment: i have a no idea for how update & delete in single element

Comment: that's just an example... you can change `multi_image` to any attribute of the object and update its value..

Comment: $i = Item::find($id);
         $image = $i->multi_image;
         $data = (json_decode($image,true));
        $myArray = array_except($data,[3]);
        print_r($myArray);
        return redirect()->back();

Comment: i use unset but not delete data in database.

Comment: I dont understand what are you trying to say..